# Where to find jobs favourites on the Stack Overflow mobile site?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, mobile-web

I am looking at job opportunities published on Stack Overflow Jobs and saving them to favourites. Where do I find the favourites list of saved jobs on the mobile version of Stack Overflow?

I see the favourites option only on the desktop version of the site.

I looked through all options like filters and jobs settings.

Comment: Isn't it at the bottom of the Jobs page (above the footer)?

Comment: @Andy In footer is Full site option which add not only favourites container below job listing. Finally this is the way how to solve this problem. Thank You for your hint.